# Why is my .listen call from Laravel echo not working in my Angular frontend?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, websocket, echo

I'm writing some front end code that is trying to listent o a websocket using Pusher and laravel. I can't get the listen event to trigger though.

I'm receiving the websocket info in the page:

Request URL: ws://localhost:6001/app/someKey?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.4.0&flash=false

Here's the websocket output in the browser when I fire a new event:

```
channel: "chat"
data: "{"user":{"id":1,"name":"1","email":"1","balance":"79558.76450989","default_leverage":"20","used_margin":"3074.6057739400","email_verified_at":null,"is_fake":"yes","created_at":"2019-03-07 11:47:22","updated_at":"2019-04-08 10:54:02"},"message":{"id":82,"user_id":1,"group_id":1,"text":"test text here","created_at":"2019-04-08 10:55:21","updated_at":"2019-04-08 10:55:21"}}"
event: "App\Events\MessageSent"
```

Here's my ts code (ionic-v4):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Echo} from 'laravel-echo-ionic';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PusherService {

  echo:any;

  constructor( ) {
    console.log("Pusher Service");
    var pusher = require('pusher-js');
    this.echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'pusher',
      wsHost: 'localhost',
      wsPort: 6001,
      key: 'someKey',
      encrypted: false,
      enabledTransports: ['ws'],
    });
    this.echo.channel('chat').listen('App\Events\MessageSent', (e) => { 
      console.log('got message')  ;
    });  
  }
}
```

I'm not getting the console log to output... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it working.

For anyone else struggling with this in the future, you can just listen to the event 'MessageSent'; you don't need the full path. I.e.

```
    this.echo.channel('chat').listen('MessageSent', (e) => { 
      console.log('got message')  ;
    });
```

will work.